# Activate WebView keyboard events

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I have a webview inside a simple/plain NSWindow.

When i load a url inside the WebView like "http://google.com" i can't interact with textfield selecting all characters (cmd+a), cutting/pasting (cmd+cv) and so on.

How can i activate the default browser behaviors?
My mac emit the classic NSBeep() instead.

I tried adding a UIDelegate wich call

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)webView shouldPerformAction:(SEL)action fromSender:(id)sender`
```

but the action is never called.

Answer (score 3):

You have to subclass WebView or any view above in the view hierarchy, where your WebView is a subview and override the **NSResponder** methods of NSView;
in particular acceptFirstResponder: and canBecomeFirstResponder:. Then implement the keyUp: or keyDown: or whatever event method of NSResponder you're interested in.

This should at least omit the NSBeep.

To intercept events deeper inside WebView (for cut/paste/etc), WebView itself also provides a couple of methods to override, though I think there must be additional steps taken to intercept events accordingly. Sorry for being vague here.

The *webView:shouldPerformAction:fromSender* you mention is not what you'd expect it to be. The [WebUIDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/WebUIDelegate_Protocol.pdf) says that this method "Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the action sent by the specified object should be performed." - But the **WebUIDelegationProtocol** methods will only be *"invoked as a result of handling JavaScript or other plug-in content"*. That means shouldPerformAction: will only be called if triggered by the website itself (JS or plugins) and not if an NSResponder Event occurs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean `NSView` instead of `UIView`, correct?